# Common Dialogboxes Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, modal-dialog

I have a common color dialog box that I want to activate on a menu press.
Unfortunately, every time I press on the item, the window loses focus, as if a dialog box is coming up, but the dialog box never shows up.

The code I'm using right now is below:

```
case ID_TOOL_CHOOSECOLOR:
//show colour dialog
ChooseColor(&cc);
```

and I've initialized my CHOOSECOLOR structure like this:

```
 cc.lStructSize    = sizeof (CHOOSECOLOR) ;
 cc.hwndOwner      = NULL ;
 cc.hInstance      = NULL ;
 cc.rgbResult      = RGB (0x80, 0x80, 0x80) ;
 cc.lpCustColors   = crCustColor ;
 cc.Flags          = CC_RGBINIT | CC_FULLOPEN ;
 cc.lCustData      = 0 ;
 cc.lpfnHook       = NULL ;
 cc.lpTemplateName = NULL ;
```

What's weird is, the dialog box only shows up after I press the "ALT" key (and only the alt key). Any tips?

I'm trying to do this in an MDI document by the way.

Thanks

Comment: try to present more complete source code.

Comment: just the single thing in the presented code that I see that isn't OK, namely you should set `hInstance` to result of `GetModuleHandle( 0 )`. a possible other problem might be failure to zero-initialize the whole structure. just declare it as `CHOOSECOLOR cc = {sizeof(cc)};`, that takes care of the zero initialization and the `lStructSize` initialization.

Comment: @Cheers The documentation disagrees re. hInstance: *If neither CC_ ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE nor CC_ENABLETEMPLATE is set, this member is ignored.* Also, all fields are initialized so zero-init won't solve this problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: API structures should always be zero-initialized before use. You never know when an OS update will add new structure fields that would then not be initialized with a code update. That is why many API structures have an `lStructSize`-style field begin with - to support structure versioning. Even if the size field is set to an older smaller structure size, leaving newer fields uninitialized has been known to cause random behavior and/or crashes.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but that's not the issue. It's just that my dialog box won't show up until I press the ALT key. I know it's there, I just don't know why. And everywhere else I've looked, no one seems to have an answer either.

Comment: @Remy Do you honestly think I don't know that? Do you think I even disagree? All I said was that wasn't the problem here.

Answer (score 5):

The only problem I can see is that you did not specify an owner for the dialog. This could lead to the dialog showing behind your main window. Specify the handle of your main window to be the dialog's owner.

Read more about window ownership on the [Window Features page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Comment: Yeah I tried that, (I set the owner of the box to hwndFrame, since it's MDI), but still nothing. I still have to press the ALT key for it to show up.

Comment: Make the main window be the owner. Read the link I gave you: *Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner
window; a child window cannot be an owner window.*

Comment: Sorry, @Cheers the dialog box isn't behind anything. It's literally not showing up anywhere on my desktop; if i hide the main window, there's nothing there.

Comment: hmm i think i figured it out...might have something to do with the fact i'm trying to open a dialog box within a MDI child. 

i tried making a MessageBox() and that wouldn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "within a child"?

Comment: I mean that the the WM_COMMAND to call choosecolor is located within the ChildWndProc, not the one in the main window.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27915/discussion-between-docaholic-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Turns out, the issue I had was in the main window's WndProc.

I had set my `WM_PAINT` command to `return 0;` instead of `break;`.

Changing my `return 0` to `break` solved everything! 
I think this is cause my `return` would exit the wndproc, whereas `break` would allow me to continue to the `return MDIFrameProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam)` .

I maybe wrong, but that's the best explanation that I can come up with that explains why `break` works but `return 0` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After you paint, make sure you call `ValidateRect(HWND,CONST RECT*);`

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/color-dialog-box
// http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32Choosing_a_Color.htm
COLORREF acrCustClr[16]; // array of custom colors
CHOOSECOLOR cc = {sizeof(cc)};
ZeroMemory(&cc, sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR));
cc.lStructSize = sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR);
cc.hwndOwner = hwnd;
cc.Flags = CC_FULLOPEN | CC_RGBINIT;
cc.lpCustColors = (LPDWORD) acrCustClr;

BOOL fOk = ChooseColor(&cc);
if (fOk) {
}
```